# What is a good project to learn OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

A friend of mine, who studies game development at an university, is currently learning programming in OpenCL. What would be a simple project that teaches the most important aspects of OpenCL and can be finished within about 50 - 100 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to your friend to implement a paper related to game development so it be will something he could put on his resume too and help him getting a job in this industry.

E.g. this one is interesting and roughly 100 hours of times:
[http://www.unibas.it/erra/Papers/HiBi09.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20150928032202/http://icouzin.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/file/PDFs/Erra%20et%20al,%202009.pdf)

Comment: Yep, nbody particle simulations with well mannered pairwise potential functions work very well on GPU and seem to be the "killer app" so far.